# AST for LDAP filter queries

Tags: ldap, abstract-syntax-tree

I was searching for open source script which can normalize the LDAP filters queries and convert LDAP filters into an AST. Any help in this direction will be appreciated.

Comment: there is a ruby library: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/ruby-ldap/ruby-net-ldap/Net/LDAP/Filter

Comment: require 'net-ldap'
  
pp Net::LDAP::Filter::FilterParser.parse("(&(a=b)(c=d))")

I think this will be the sample code to parse LDAP filter (&(a=b)(c=d))